# JPA Hibernate InheritanceType.JOINED SchemaManagementException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-design

I have a parent entity class with two children entity classes. On the parent class there are three properties which are annotated with @ManyToOne and five other properties which are annotated with @Column.

Hibernate wants the three properties (country, exchange, sector) which are annotated with @ManyToOne to be present in the children db tables (future and stock).

When these three FK properties are not present in the db tables "future" and "stock", the following exception is thrown: **org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [country_id] in table [future]**

Any idea why ? 
Do foreign key columns need to be repeated/added into the child DB table ?

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;
}
```

---

**Parent : Instrument**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="instr_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)
@Table(name = "instrument")

public class Instrument extends BaseEntity {              

    @Column
    private String symbol;

    @Column
    private String isin;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LiquidEnum liquid;

    @Column
    private boolean active;

    // FK

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "instrument_country_fk"))
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "exchange_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "instrument_exchange_fk"))
    private Exchange exchange;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sector_id", nullable = true, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "instrument_sector_fk"))
    private Sector sector;

    // FK end

    getter / setter
    ...
}
```

---

**child class : Future**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "future")
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Future extends Instrument {

    @Column(name = "expirationdate")
    private LocalDate expirationDate;

    public LocalDate getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate;
    }

    public void setExpirationdate(LocalDate expirationDate) {
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }
}
```

---

**child class : Stock**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Stock extends Instrument  {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem : the foreign key objects (country, exchange, sector) are referring to the Stock entity instead of the Instrument entity.

When I refactored the db model with the inheritance strategy (adding a parent the entity "Instrument"), I forgot to redirect the @OneToMany attributes in Country, Exchange and Sector towards the Instrument entity.